# Google 2-step authentication

Tags: php

How does Google 2-step authentication identify a computer?

How does it know i have verified this device before? and that it hasn't passed 30 days?

Are we using cookies here?

Comment: Getting started with 2-step verification http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1056283

Comment: Anyone know of a PHP class to handle this?

Comment: a php class to handle goolge 2-step authentication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done with cookies. The 2-step process just makes sure that you are who you claim to be, or at least makes it a little harder to get around simple password authentication.